# Why do I get an error: cannot decompose inaccessible member when compiling this code using std::views::chunk?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, c++23

This code compiles and works correctly:

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const auto r = std::views::iota('a', static_cast<char>('g' + 1));

    for(const auto& [start, end] : r | std::views::chunk(3u)) {
        for(auto it = start; it != end; ++it) {
            std::cout << *it << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is:

```
a b c 
d e f 
g
```

If I change the definition of `r` as follows:

```cpp
const auto r = std::views::iota('a', 'g' + 1);
```

The code does not compile. GCC 13 emits the following error:

```
chunk.cpp:13:21: error: cannot decompose inaccessible member ‘std::ranges::take_view<std::ranges::subrange<std::ranges::iota_view<char, int>::_Iterator, std::ranges::iota_view<char, int>::_Sentinel, std::ranges::subrange_kind::unsized> >::_M_base’ of ‘const std::ranges::take_view<std::ranges::subrange<std::ranges::iota_view<char, int>::_Iterator, std::ranges::iota_view<char, int>::_Sentinel, std::ranges::subrange_kind::unsized> >’
   13 |     for(const auto& [start, end] : r | std::views::chunk(3u)) {
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from chunk.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/13/ranges:2153:11: note: declared private here
 2153 |       _Vp _M_base = _Vp();
      |           ^~~~~~~
```

I think that `'g' + 1` is causing integer promotion and is making the first and second parameter of `iota()` have different types. However, in other occasions, this seems fine. For example, this code works as expected:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const auto r = std::views::iota('a', 'g' + 1);

    for(const auto& val : r) {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

What is happening here? And why does the error mentions (of all things) private members?

Comment: Not a complete answer,, but hopefully a sth helpful: depending on the conversion to char the inner range of chunked becomes sized (for char) or unsized (for char-int pair). Not sure if that is correct behaviour here. https://godbolt.org/z/r7Tb9KxEh

Comment: I too think 'g' + 1 is promoting to int. And since views are templates no implicit conversion (back to) char is considered. And that's why you need the explicit conversion.

Comment: @PepijnKramer it is promoting for sure. But the problem is contextual and manifests itself when taking range and passing it to another adapter. With just `iota` it works fine and the promotion does not break anything; moreover the resulting range is always sized.

Comment: Seems to me that it all stems from the fact `sized_sentinel_for` in case of char-int pair is unsatisfied. The question is though, whys `size()` is avaialable for it, see:
https://godbolt.org/z/YKGWMqbPY

Comment: @alagner "*The question is though, whys size() is avaialable for it*" Because `views::iota('a', int('g' + 1))` has a `size()` member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `'g' + 1` produces integer promotions, this makes `views::iota('a', 'g' + 1)` produce an `iota_view` whose iterator type is different from the sentinel type.

According to [[range.iota.sentinel]](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.iota.sentinel), the sentinel type can only be subtracted from the iterator type when `sized_sentinel_for<W, Bound>` is satisfied, which is not the case for the basic types `char` and `int` because they are not iterators.

In other words, this breaks `iota_view`'s sentinel and iterator subtraction functionality:

```
auto r = views::iota('a', 'g' + 1);
r.begin() - r.end(); // error
```

When applying `views::chunck` to it, the resulting value type would be `decltype(views::take(subrange(current_, end_), n_))` ([[range.chunk.fwd.iter]](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.chunk.fwd.iter)), where `current_` and `end_` is the iterator and sentinel of this `iota_view`.

Since `current_` and `end_` no longer model `sized_sentinel_for`,  CTAD will deduce a `subrange` with the third template parameter (`subrange_kind`) is `unsized` ([[range.subrange.general]](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.subrange.general)), and such a `subrange` is no longer `sized_range`:

```
auto r = views::iota('a', 'g' + 1);
auto s = ranges::subrange(r.begin(), r.end());
static_assert(ranges::sized_range<decltype(s)>); // failed
```

This makes `views::take` return a `take_view` object ([[range.take.overview#2.5]](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.take.overview#2.5)), which cannot be structured binding.

For your original example, since the iterator type of `views::iota('a', 'g')` is the same as the sentinel type and the two can be subtracted, `subrange(current_, end_)` will still model `sized_range` and `random_access_range`. In this case, `views::take` will optimally return a `subrange` type that can be structured binding ([[range.take.overview#2.2.3]](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.take.overview#2.2.3)).

This can arguably be seen as a defect in the standard, which is also [LWG 3609](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3609).